# MVC grid sorting - customise links

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using the Sort method of the MvcContrib Grid to generate sorting links, e.g.

```
<%= Html.Grid(Model).AutoGenerateColumns().Sort((GridSortOptions)ViewData["sort"]) %>
```

I have a need to change the default controller/action that’s generated  by the sort method. For example,

```
defaultControllerName/defaultActionName/?Column=ProductId&Direction=Ascending
```

would change to

```
customControllerName/customActionName/?Column=ProductId&Direction=Ascending
```

I haven't been able to find any existing methods in the MVCcontribution classes that would allow me to customise the links. I’d appreciate any pointers on how to go about altering the default links as I’m still very much a MVC/C# newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an easy task. You will need a custom grid renderer to achieve this and override the RenderHeaderText method:

```
public class MyHtmlTableGridRenderer<T> : HtmlTableGridRenderer<T> where TViewModel : class
{
    protected override void RenderHeaderText(GridColumn<TViewModel> column)
    {
        if (IsSortingEnabled && column.Sortable)
        {
            // TODO: generate a custom link here based on the sorting options
            string text = ...
            base.RenderText(text);
        }
        else
        {
            RenderText(column.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

And then specify that the grid should use this renderer:

```
.RenderUsing(new MyHtmlTableGridRenderer<Employee>())
```

Comment: Many thanks for the above example. Substituting the null parameters in GenerateLink method was the only change I had to make to the override method

Comment: for example - var link = HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(Context.RequestContext, RouteTable.Routes, column.DisplayName, null, "Index", "Home", routeValues, null);

Comment: How is the routeValues parameter filled? I tried: var routeValues = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(new { Column = column.SortColumnName, Direction = column.??? }); Where is the direction stored?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide a complete working example:

```
public class SortableHtmlTableGridRenderer<T> : HtmlTableGridRenderer<T> where T : class
{
    readonly string _action;
    readonly string _controllerName;

    public SortableHtmlTableGridRenderer(string action, string controllerName)
    {
        _action = action;
        _controllerName = controllerName;
    }

    protected override void RenderHeaderText(GridColumn<T> column)
    {
        if (IsSortingEnabled && column.Sortable)
        {
            string sortColumnName = GenerateSortColumnName(column);

            bool isSortedByThisColumn = GridModel.SortOptions.Column == sortColumnName;

            var sortOptions = new GridSortOptions
            {
                Column = sortColumnName
            };

            if (isSortedByThisColumn)
            {
                sortOptions.Direction = (GridModel.SortOptions.Direction == SortDirection.Ascending)
                    ? SortDirection.Descending
                    : SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            else //default sort order
            {
                sortOptions.Direction = column.InitialDirection ?? GridModel.SortOptions.Direction;
            }

            var routeValues = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(new {sortOptions.Column, sortOptions.Direction });
            var text = HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(Context.RequestContext, RouteTable.Routes, column.DisplayName, null, _action, _controllerName, routeValues, null);
            RenderText(text);
        }
        else
        {
            RenderText(column.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
.RenderUsing(new SortableHtmlTableGridRenderer<YourModelType>("Search", "Search"))
```